# Missing STOPKEY per partition in Oracle plan for paging by local index

Tags: sql, oracle, prepared-statement, partitioning, sql-execution-plan

There is next partitioned table:

```
CREATE TABLE "ERMB_LOG_TEST_BF"."OUT_SMS"(
    "TRX_ID" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "CREATE_TS" TIMESTAMP (3) DEFAULT systimestamp NOT NULL ENABLE,
    /* other fields... */
) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
  STORAGE(BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ERMB_LOG_TEST_BF"
  PARTITION BY RANGE ("TRX_ID") INTERVAL (281474976710656)
  (PARTITION "SYS_P1358"  VALUES LESS THAN (59109745109237760) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
  NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ERMB_LOG_TEST_BF");

CREATE INDEX "ERMB_LOG_TEST_BF"."OUT_SMS_CREATE_TS_TRX_ID_IX" ON "ERMB_LOG_TEST_BF"."OUT_SMS" ("CREATE_TS" DESC, "TRX_ID" DESC)
    PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255
    STORAGE(
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) LOCAL
    (PARTITION "SYS_P1358"
    PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 LOGGING
    STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
    PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE "ERMB_LOG_TEST_BF");
```

I have sql query, which select 20 records ordered by date and transaction:

```
select rd from (
    select /*+ INDEX(OUT_SMS OUT_SMS_CREATE_TS_TRX_ID_IX) */ rowid rd
    from OUT_SMS     
    where  TRX_ID between 34621422135410688 and 72339069014638591       
       and CREATE_TS between to_timestamp('2013-02-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
                         and to_timestamp('2013-03-06 08:57:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')       
    order by CREATE_TS DESC, TRX_ID DESC
) where rownum <= 20
```

Oracle has generated next plan:

```
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                   | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                             |    20 |   240 |       |  4788K  (1)| 00:05:02 |       |       |
    |*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY              |                             |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
    |   2 |   VIEW                      |                             |   312M|  3576M|       |  4788K  (1)| 00:05:02 |       |       |
    |*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY    |                             |   312M|     9G|    12G|  4788K  (1)| 00:05:02 |       |       |
    |   4 |     PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|                             |   312M|     9G|       |    19   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |    48 |
    |*  5 |      COUNT STOPKEY          |                             |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
    |*  6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN      | OUT_SMS_CREATE_TS_TRX_ID_IX |   312M|     9G|       |    19   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |    48 |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ---------------------------------------------------

    1 - filter(ROWNUM<=20)
    3 - filter(ROWNUM<=20)
    5 - filter(ROWNUM<=20)
    6 - access(SYS_OP_DESCEND("CREATE_TS")>=HEXTORAW('878EFCF9F6C5FEFAFF')  AND
    SYS_OP_DESCEND("TRX_ID")>=HEXTORAW('36F7E7D7F8A4F0BFA9A3FF')  AND
    SYS_OP_DESCEND("CREATE_TS")<=HEXTORAW('878EFDFEF8FEF8FF')  AND
    SYS_OP_DESCEND("TRX_ID")<=HEXTORAW('36FBD0E9D4E9DBD5F8A6FF') )
    filter(SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("CREATE_TS"))<=TIMESTAMP' 2013-03-06 08:57:00,000000000' AND
    SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("TRX_ID"))<=72339069014638591 AND
    SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("TRX_ID"))>=34621422135410688 AND
    SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("CREATE_TS"))>=TIMESTAMP' 2013-02-01 00:00:00,000000000')
```

It works perfectly.

By the way, table `OUT_SMS` is **partitioned** by `TRX_ID` field and `OUT_SMS_CREATE_TS_TRX_ID_IX` is **local index** `(CREATE_TS DESC, TRX_ID DESC)` on each partition.

But if I convert this query to **prepared statement**:

```
select rd from (
    select /*+ INDEX(OUT_SMS OUT_SMS_CREATE_TS_TRX_ID_IX) */ rowid rd
    from OUT_SMS     
    where  TRX_ID between ? and ?       
       and CREATE_TS between ? and ?
    order by CREATE_TS DESC, TRX_ID DESC
) where rownum <= 20
```

Oracle generates next plan:

```
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                    | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                             |    20 |   240 | 14743   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY               |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |
    |   2 |   VIEW                       |                             |  1964 | 23568 | 14743   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY     |                             |  1964 | 66776 | 14743   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
    |*  4 |     FILTER                   |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |
    |   5 |      PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|                             |  1964 | 66776 | 14742   (1)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
    |*  6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN       | OUT_SMS_CREATE_TS_TRX_ID_IX |  1964 | 66776 | 14742   (1)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ---------------------------------------------------

    1 - filter(ROWNUM<=20)
    3 - filter(ROWNUM<=20)
    4 - filter(TO_TIMESTAMP(:RR,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')<=TO_TIMESTAMP(:T,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND
    TO_NUMBER(:ABC)<=TO_NUMBER(:EBC))
    6 - access(SYS_OP_DESCEND("CREATE_TS")>=SYS_OP_DESCEND(TO_TIMESTAMP(:T,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')) AND
    SYS_OP_DESCEND("TRX_ID")>=SYS_OP_DESCEND(TO_NUMBER(:EBC)) AND
    SYS_OP_DESCEND("CREATE_TS")<=SYS_OP_DESCEND(TO_TIMESTAMP(:RR,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')) AND
    SYS_OP_DESCEND("TRX_ID")<=SYS_OP_DESCEND(TO_NUMBER(:ABC)))
    filter(SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("TRX_ID"))>=TO_NUMBER(:ABC) AND
    SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("TRX_ID"))<=TO_NUMBER(:EBC) AND
    SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("CREATE_TS"))>=TO_TIMESTAMP(:RR,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND
    SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("CREATE_TS"))<=TO_TIMESTAMP(:T,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

Operation **COUNT STOPKEY** disappears from plan. This operation should be after index was analyzed for getting 20 rows from each partition like the first query.

How can I compose prepared statement to have COUNT STOPKEY in the plan?

Comment: What is the prepared statement and '?' in 'between ? and ?' ? Can only give you one advice about dates. To compare dates remove the time portion with trunc() unless you really need to compare to the seconds. Use row_number() instead of rownum.

Comment: What type of partitioning is involved here? Best show the table and index DDL. Also, use DBMS_Xplan to get the execution plan and paste it into the question rather than linking to images please.

Comment: "Is the intention that the query only retrieve rows from a single partition?" - No. I have to fetch data from several partitions.

Comment: This is a "known" problem when using bind variables. You didn't specify your Oracle version, but 11.2 has improved quite substantially here (it re-checks the execution plan to see if the assumptions hold true after executing the statement). I don't think you can fix this using a prepared statement. This is one of the rare cases where *not* using binds is better.

Comment: Yeah bind variables and partitions have not always played well together -- witness the PSTART and PSTOP values of KEY. you don't mention why you want to use a prepared statement, but I'd also avoid using them on the partition key.

Comment: Yes, I use 11.2.0. Thank you guys for your attention. May be there is  some official forum thread about this problem. It will be good answer for this question.

Answer (score 10):

When you use bind variables, Oracle is forced to use [dynamic partition pruning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_avail.htm#BABFGAEC) instead of [static partition pruning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_avail.htm#BABEGHBB). The result of this is that Oracle doesn't know at parse time which partitions will be accessed, as this changes based on your input variables.

This means that when using literal values (instead of bind variables), we know which partitions will be accessed by your local index. Therefore the `count stopkey` can be applied to the output of the index before we prune the partitions.

When using bind variables, the `partition range iterator` has to figure out which partitions you're accessing. It then has a check to ensure that the first of your variables in the between operations do actually have a lower value then the second one (the `filter` operation in the second plan).

This can easily be reproduced, as the following test case shows:

```
create table tab (
  x date,
  y integer,
  filler varchar2(100)
) partition by range(x) (
  partition p1 values less than (date'2013-01-01'),
  partition p2 values less than (date'2013-02-01'),
  partition p3 values less than (date'2013-03-01'),
  partition p4 values less than (date'2013-04-01'),
  partition p5 values less than (date'2013-05-01'),
  partition p6 values less than (date'2013-06-01')
);


insert into tab (x, y)
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'y'), mod(rownum, 5)), rownum, dbms_random.string('x', 50)
  from   dual 
  connect by level <= 1000;

create index i on tab(x desc, y desc) local;

exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'tab', cascade => true);

explain plan for 
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT rowid FROM tab
  where  x between date'2013-01-01' and date'2013-02-02'
  and    y between 50 and 100
  order  by x desc, y desc
)
where rownum <= 5;

SELECT * FROM table(dbms_xplan.display(null, null, 'BASIC +ROWS +PARTITION'));

--------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
| Id  | Operation                   | Name | Rows  | Pstart| Pstop |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |      |     1 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
|   1 |  COUNT STOPKEY              |      |       |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
|   2 |   VIEW                      |      |     1 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
|   3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY    |      |     1 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
|   4 |     PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|      |     1 |     2 |     3 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
|   5 |      COUNT STOPKEY          |      |       |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
|   6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN      | I    |     1 |     2 |     3 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
-------------------------------------------------------------------- 

explain plan for 
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT rowid FROM tab
  where  x between to_date(:st, 'dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date(:en, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
  and    y between :a and :b
  order  by x desc, y desc
)
where rownum <= 5;

SELECT * FROM table(dbms_xplan.display(null, null, 'BASIC +ROWS +PARTITION'));

---------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
| Id  | Operation                    | Name | Rows  | Pstart| Pstop |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |      |     1 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|   1 |  COUNT STOPKEY               |      |       |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|   2 |   VIEW                       |      |     1 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|   3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY     |      |     1 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|   4 |     FILTER                   |      |       |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|   5 |      PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|      |     1 |   KEY |   KEY |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|   6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN       | I    |     1 |   KEY |   KEY |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As in your example, the second query can only filter the partitions to a `key` at parse time, rather than the exact partitions as in the first example.

This is one of those rare cases where literal values can provide better performance than bind variables. You should investigate whether this is a possibility for you.

Finally, you say you want 20 rows from each partition. Your query as stands won't do this, it'll just return you the first 20 rows according to your ordering. For 20 rows/partition, you need to do something like this:

```
select rd from (
    select rowid rd, 
           row_number() over (partition by trx_id order by create_ts desc) rn
    from OUT_SMS     
    where  TRX_ID between ? and ?       
       and CREATE_TS between ? and ?
    order by CREATE_TS DESC, TRX_ID DESC
) where rn <= 20
```

**UPDATE**

The reason you're not getting the `count stopkey` is to do with the `filter` operation in line 4 of the "bad" plan. You can see this more clearly if you repeat the example above, but with no partitioning.

This gives you the following plans:

```
----------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
| Id  | Operation               | Name |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
----------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY          |      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   2 |   VIEW                  |      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY|      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL   | TAB  |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
----------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=5)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   3 - filter(ROWNUM<=5)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   4 - filter("X">=TO_DATE(' 2013-01-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
              hh24:mi:ss') AND "X"<=TO_DATE(' 2013-02-02 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
              hh24:mi:ss') AND "Y">=50 AND "Y"<=100)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

----------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
| Id  | Operation               | Name |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
----------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY          |      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   2 |   VIEW                  |      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY|      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|*  4 |     FILTER              |      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL  | TAB  |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
----------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=5)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   3 - filter(ROWNUM<=5)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   4 - filter(TO_NUMBER(:A)<=TO_NUMBER(:B) AND                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
              TO_DATE(:ST,'dd/mm/yyyy')<=TO_DATE(:EN,'dd/mm/yyyy'))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   5 - filter("Y">=TO_NUMBER(:A) AND "Y"<=TO_NUMBER(:B) AND                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
              "X">=TO_DATE(:ST,'dd/mm/yyyy') AND "X"<=TO_DATE(:EN,'dd/mm/yyyy'))
```

As you can see, there's an extra `filter` operation when you use bind variables appearing before the `sort order by stopkey`. This happens after accessing the index. This is checking that the values for the variables will allow data to be returned (the first variable in your between does actually have a lower value than the second). This isn't necessary when using literals because the optimizer already knows that 50 is less than 100 (in this case). It doesn't know whether :a is less than :b at parse time however.

Why exactly this is I don't know. It could be intentional design by Oracle - there's no point doing the stopkey check if the values set for the variables result in zero rows - or just an oversight.

Comment: The difference is that in the first case the COUNT STOPKEY is pushed **inside** the partition range index scan, which means that Oracle is smart enough to realize that in order to get 20 rows total, it doesn't need more than 20 rows per partition. This subtlety is lost when using bind variables. I don't see why dynamic partition pruning couldn't be enhanced to push the rownum predicate in each partition scan. You don't really give a valid reason for this behaviour, nor a good workaround =)

Comment: @VincentMalgrat - well, I'd argue that "not using bind variables" is a workaround, though not necessarily desirable! If the query is executed infrequently and/or there's a limited number of values used in the filter on `trx_id` then the additional parsing overhead should be minimal, making this a possible approach.

Comment: I agree with your workaround, unfortunately the OP seems to want to use bind variables. I disagree with your explanation though =) the `FILTER` doesn't replace the `COUNT STOPKEY` since they are fundamentally distinct operations. As you explain the `FILTER` allows Oracle to branch out impossible operations. The `COUNT STOPKEY` is an optimization that allows Oracle to fetch only 20 rows per partition since it needs 20 rows total. When using bind variables, this optimization is absent, this is likely a bug (see related metalink bugs 12873183 and 8500130).

Comment: Agree with Vincent. If you want properly see what i'm talking about, you should load 500 millions rows in 10 partitions (i'm testing on this number). `FILTER` operation doesn't help. Can help only `COUNT STOPKEY` on local index.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat - I'm not saying that the `filter` _replaces_ the `count stopkey`, or that this is necessarily "good", just that this is what Oracle is choosing to do. Looking at bug 12873183, it seems to me they consider pushing the `count stopkey` inside the `partition iterator` a bug, so the desired behaviour will be lost when applying the latest patchset (11.2.0.3.5).

Comment: No, this is a bug because it returns the wrong results not because the plan is wrong. Look at bug 8500130, it clearly states "When you observe terrible performance on queries with rownum predicate, and
see that there is **no rownum predicate processing under partition iterators**, you may have encountered this bug.". Also bug 13972896 seems to imply that not pushing the ROWNUM predicate is a bug.

Comment: @ChrisSaxon, thanks for the clue on bounds checking filter. It helped me to find a suitable workaround described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357571/missing-stopkey-per-partition-in-oracle-plan-for-paging-by-local-index/50271629#50271629) here.

Answer (score 8):

I can reproduce your findings on 11.2.0.3. Here's my test case:

```
SQL> -- Table with 100 partitions of 100 rows 
SQL> CREATE TABLE out_sms
  2  PARTITION BY RANGE (trx_id)
  3     INTERVAL (100) (PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (0))
  4  AS
  5  SELECT ROWNUM trx_id,
  6         trunc(SYSDATE) + MOD(ROWNUM, 50) create_ts
  7  FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10000;

Table created

SQL> CREATE INDEX OUT_SMS_IDX ON out_sms (create_ts desc, trx_id desc) LOCAL;

Index created

[static plan]

SELECT rd
  FROM (SELECT /*+ INDEX(OUT_SMS OUT_SMS_IDX) */
         rowid rd
          FROM out_sms
         WHERE create_ts BETWEEN systimestamp AND systimestamp + 10
           AND trx_id BETWEEN 1 AND 500
         ORDER BY create_ts DESC, trx_id DESC)
 WHERE rownum <= 20;    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name        | Rows  | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |             |     1 |       |       |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY              |             |       |       |       |
|   2 |   VIEW                      |             |     1 |       |       |
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY    |             |     1 |       |       |
|   4 |     PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|             |     1 |     2 |     7 |
|*  5 |      COUNT STOPKEY          |             |       |       |       |
|*  6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN      | OUT_SMS_IDX |     1 |     2 |     7 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

[dynamic]     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name        | Rows  | Pstart| Pstop |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |             |     1 |       |       |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY               |             |       |       |       |
|   2 |   VIEW                       |             |     1 |       |       |
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY     |             |     1 |       |       |
|*  4 |     FILTER                   |             |       |       |       |
|   5 |      PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|             |     1 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN       | OUT_SMS_IDX |     1 |   KEY |   KEY |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As in your example the `ROWNUM` predicate is pushed **inside** the partition index range scan in the first case, not in the second case. When using static variables, the plan shows that Oracle fetches only 20 rows per partition, whereas using dynamic variables, Oracle will fetch **all** rows that satisfy the `WHERE` clause in each partition. I couldn't find a setting or a statistics configuration where the predicate could be pushed when using bind variables.

I hoped that you could use dynamic filters with wider static limits to game the system but it seems that the `ROWNUM` predicate isn't used inside individual partitions as soon as there are dynamic variables present:

```
SELECT rd
  FROM (SELECT /*+ INDEX(OUT_SMS OUT_SMS_IDX) */
         rowid rd
          FROM out_sms
         WHERE nvl(create_ts+:5, sysdate) BETWEEN :1 AND :2
           AND nvl(trx_id+:6, 0) BETWEEN :3 AND :4
           AND trx_id BETWEEN 1 AND 500
           AND create_ts BETWEEN systimestamp AND systimestamp + 10
         ORDER BY create_ts DESC, trx_id DESC)
 WHERE rownum <= 20

Plan hash value: 2740263591

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name        | Rows  | Pstart| Pstop |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |             |     1 |       |       |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY               |             |       |       |       |
|   2 |   VIEW                       |             |     1 |       |       |
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY     |             |     1 |       |       |
|*  4 |     FILTER                   |             |       |       |       |
|   5 |      PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|             |     1 |     2 |     7 |
|*  6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN       | OUT_SMS_IDX |     1 |     2 |     7 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If this query is important and its performance is critical, you could transform the index to a global index. It will increase partition maintenance but most partition operations can be used online with recent Oracle versions. A global index will work as with standard non-partitioned table in this case:

```
SQL> drop index out_sms_idx;

Index dropped

SQL> CREATE INDEX OUT_SMS_IDX ON out_sms (create_ts DESC, trx_id desc);

Index created

SELECT rd
  FROM (SELECT 
         rowid rd
          FROM out_sms
         WHERE create_ts BETWEEN :1 AND :2
           AND trx_id BETWEEN :3 AND :4
         ORDER BY create_ts DESC, trx_id DESC)
 WHERE rownum <= 20

------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |             |     1 |    12 |     2   (0)|
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY      |             |       |       |            |
|   2 |   VIEW              |             |     1 |    12 |     2   (0)|
|*  3 |    FILTER           |             |       |       |            |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN| OUT_SMS_IDX |     1 |    34 |     2   (0)|
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I get your idea about global index, but number of the rows could be very big and I will lose partition benefits.

Comment: Here are more details on [Asynchronous Global Index Maintenance during partition drop](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128049/drop-partition-and-rebuild-global-indexes-online).

Comment: @Vincent, if you are still interested in a workaroud to push `COUNT STOPKEY` down take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357571/missing-stopkey-per-partition-in-oracle-plan-for-paging-by-local-index/50271629#50271629).

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that the issue in question is still a problem on Oracle 12.1.0.2.0.

And even hardcoded [partition elimination](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-E677C85E-C5E3-4927-B3DF-684007A7B05D.htm#VLDBG00401) bounds are not enough.

Here is the test table in my case:

```
CREATE TABLE FR_MESSAGE_PART (
    ID NUMBER(38) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_FR_MESSAGE_PART PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX LOCAL,
    TRX_ID NUMBER(38) NOT NULL, TS TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, TEXT CLOB)
    PARTITION BY RANGE (ID) (PARTITION PART_0 VALUES LESS THAN (0));
CREATE INDEX IX_FR_MESSAGE_PART_TRX_ID ON FR_MESSAGE_PART(TRX_ID) LOCAL;
CREATE INDEX IX_FR_MESSAGE_PART_TS ON FR_MESSAGE_PART(TS) LOCAL;
```

The table is populated with several millions of records of OLTP production data for several months. Each month belongs to a separate partition.

Primary key values of this table always include time part in higher bits that allows to use `ID` for range partitioning by calendar periods. All messages inherit higher time bits of `TRX_ID`. This ensures that all messages belonging to the same business operation do always fall in the same partition.

Let's start with hardcoded query for selecting a page of the most recent messages for a given time period with partition elimination bounds applied:

```
select * from (select * from FR_MESSAGE_PART
where TS >= DATE '2017-11-30' and TS < DATE '2017-12-02'
  and ID >= 376894993815568384 and ID < 411234940974268416
order by TS DESC) where ROWNUM <= 40;
```

But, having freshly gathered table statistics, Oracle optimizer still falsely estimates that sorting two entire monthly partitions would be faster than a range scan for two days by existing local index:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name            | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                 |    40 | 26200 |       |   103K  (1)| 00:00:05 |       |       |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY              |                 |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   VIEW                      |                 |   803K|   501M|       |   103K  (1)| 00:00:05 |       |       |
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY    |                 |   803K|    70M|    92M|   103K  (1)| 00:00:05 |       |       |
|   4 |     PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|                 |   803K|    70M|       | 86382   (1)| 00:00:04 |     2 |     3 |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL      | FR_MESSAGE_PART |   803K|    70M|       | 86382   (1)| 00:00:04 |     2 |     3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   3 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   5 - filter("TS"<TIMESTAMP' 2017-12-01 00:00:00' AND "TS">=TIMESTAMP' 2017-11-29 00:00:00' AND 
              "ID">=376894993815568384)
```

Actual execution time appears by an order of magnitude longer than estimated in plan.

So we have to apply a hint to force usage of the index:

```
select * from (select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(40) INDEX(FR_MESSAGE_PART (TS)) */ * from FR_MESSAGE_PART
where TS >= DATE '2017-11-30' and TS < DATE '2017-12-02'
  and ID >= 376894993815568384 and ID < 411234940974268416
order by TS DESC) where ROWNUM <= 40;
```

Now the plan uses the index but still envolves slow sorting of two entire partitions:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                     | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                              |                       |    40 | 26200 |       |   615K  (1)| 00:00:25 |       |       |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                                |                       |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   VIEW                                        |                       |   803K|   501M|       |   615K  (1)| 00:00:25 |       |       |
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY                      |                       |   803K|    70M|    92M|   615K  (1)| 00:00:25 |       |       |
|   4 |     PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR                  |                       |   803K|    70M|       |   598K  (1)| 00:00:24 |     2 |     3 |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED| FR_MESSAGE_PART       |   803K|    70M|       |   598K  (1)| 00:00:24 |     2 |     3 |
|*  6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                        | IX_FR_MESSAGE_PART_TS |   576K|       |       |  2269   (1)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   3 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   5 - filter("ID">=376894993815568384)
   6 - access("TS">=TIMESTAMP' 2017-11-30 00:00:00' AND "TS"<TIMESTAMP' 2017-12-02 00:00:00')
```

After some struggling through [Oracle hints reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10752/hintsref.htm) and google it was found that we also have to explicitly specify the descending direction for index range scan with [INDEX_DESC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10752/hintsref.htm#5259) or [INDEX_RS_DESC](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_hint_index_rs_asc.htm) hint:

```
select * from (select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(40) INDEX_RS_DESC(FR_MESSAGE_PART (TS)) */ * from FR_MESSAGE_PART
where TS >= DATE '2017-11-30' and TS < DATE '2017-12-02'
  and ID >= 376894993815568384 and ID < 411234940974268416
order by TS DESC) where ROWNUM <= 40;
```

This at last gives fast plan with `COUNT STOPKEY` per partition which scans partitions in descending order and sorts only at most 40 rows from each partition:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                      | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                               |                       |    40 | 26200 |       |   615K  (1)| 00:00:25 |       |       |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                                 |                       |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   VIEW                                         |                       |   803K|   501M|       |   615K  (1)| 00:00:25 |       |       |
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY                       |                       |   803K|    70M|    92M|   615K  (1)| 00:00:25 |       |       |
|   4 |     PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR                   |                       |   803K|    70M|       |   598K  (1)| 00:00:24 |     3 |     2 |
|*  5 |      COUNT STOPKEY                             |                       |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED| FR_MESSAGE_PART       |   803K|    70M|       |   598K  (1)| 00:00:24 |     3 |     2 |
|*  7 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN DESCENDING             | IX_FR_MESSAGE_PART_TS |   576K|       |       |  2269   (1)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     2 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   3 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   5 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   6 - filter("ID">=376894993815568384)
   7 - access("TS">=TIMESTAMP' 2017-11-30 00:00:00' AND "TS"<TIMESTAMP' 2017-12-02 00:00:00')
       filter("TS">=TIMESTAMP' 2017-11-30 00:00:00' AND "TS"<TIMESTAMP' 2017-12-02 00:00:00')
```

This runs blazing fast but estimated plan cost is still falsely too high.

So far so good. Now let's try to make the query parametrized to be used in our custom ORM framework:

```
select * from (select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(40) INDEX_RS_DESC(FR_MESSAGE_PART (TS)) */ * from FR_MESSAGE_PART
where TS >= :1 and TS < :2
  and ID >= :3 and ID < :4
order by TS DESC) where ROWNUM <= 40;
```

But then `COUNT STOPKEY` per partition disappears from the plan as stated in the question and confirmed in the other answer:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                      | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                               |                       |    40 | 26200 | 82349   (1)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                                 |                       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   VIEW                                         |                       |   153 |    97K| 82349   (1)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY                       |                       |   153 | 14076 | 82349   (1)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
|*  4 |     FILTER                                     |                       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   5 |      PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR                  |                       |   153 | 14076 | 82348   (1)| 00:00:04 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED| FR_MESSAGE_PART       |   153 | 14076 | 82348   (1)| 00:00:04 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  7 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN DESCENDING             | IX_FR_MESSAGE_PART_TS |   110K|       |   450   (1)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   3 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   4 - filter(TO_NUMBER(:4)>TO_NUMBER(:3) AND TO_TIMESTAMP(:2)>TO_TIMESTAMP(:1))
   6 - filter("ID">=TO_NUMBER(:3) AND "ID"<TO_NUMBER(:4))
   7 - access("TS">=TO_TIMESTAMP(:1) AND "TS"<TO_TIMESTAMP(:2))
       filter("TS">=TO_TIMESTAMP(:1) AND "TS"<TO_TIMESTAMP(:2))
```

Then I tried to retreat to hardcoded monthly-aligned partition elimination bounds but still retain parametrized timestamp bounds to minimize [plan cache spoiling](https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-16/planning-for-reuse).

```
select * from (select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(40) INDEX_RS_DESC(FR_MESSAGE_PART (TS)) */ * from FR_MESSAGE_PART
where TS >= :1 and TS < :2
  and ID >= 376894993815568384 and ID < 411234940974268416
order by TS DESC) where ROWNUM <= 40;
```

But still got slow plan:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                      | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                               |                       |    40 | 26200 |       | 83512   (1)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                                 |                       |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   VIEW                                         |                       | 61238 |    38M|       | 83512   (1)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY                       |                       | 61238 |  5501K|  7216K| 83512   (1)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
|*  4 |     FILTER                                     |                       |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   5 |      PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR                  |                       | 61238 |  5501K|       | 82214   (1)| 00:00:04 |     3 |     2 |
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED| FR_MESSAGE_PART       | 61238 |  5501K|       | 82214   (1)| 00:00:04 |     3 |     2 |
|*  7 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN DESCENDING             | IX_FR_MESSAGE_PART_TS | 79076 |       |       |   316   (1)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     2 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   3 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   4 - filter(TO_TIMESTAMP(:2)>TO_TIMESTAMP(:1))
   6 - filter("ID">=376894993815568384)
   7 - access("TS">=TO_TIMESTAMP(:1) AND "TS"<TO_TIMESTAMP(:2))
       filter("TS">=TO_TIMESTAMP(:1) AND "TS"<TO_TIMESTAMP(:2))
```

@ChrisSaxon in his answer here has mentioned that missing nested `STOPKEY COUNT` has something to do with `filter(TO_TIMESTAMP(:2)>TO_TIMESTAMP(:1))` operation which validates that the upper bound is really bigger than the lower one.

Taking this into account I tried to cheat the oprimizer by transforming `TS between :a and :b` into equivalent `:b between TS and TS + (:b - :a)`. And this worked!

After some additional investigation of the root cause of this change, I've found that just replacing `TS >= :1 and TS < :2` with `TS + 0 >= :1 and TS < :2` helps to achieve optimal execution plan.

```
select * from (select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(40) INDEX_RS_DESC(FR_MESSAGE_PART (TS)) */ * from FR_MESSAGE_PART
where TS + 0 >= :1 and TS < :2
  and ID >= 376894993815568384 and ID < 411234940974268416
order by TS DESC) where ROWNUM <= 40;
```

The plan now has proper `COUNT STOPKEY` per partition and a notion of `INTERNAL_FUNCTION("TS")+0` which prevented the toxic extra bounds checking filter, I guess.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                      | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                               |                       |    40 | 26200 |       | 10120   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                                 |                       |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   VIEW                                         |                       | 61238 |    38M|       | 10120   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY                       |                       | 61238 |  5501K|  7216K| 10120   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   4 |     PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR                   |                       | 61238 |  5501K|       |  8822   (1)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     2 |
|*  5 |      COUNT STOPKEY                             |                       |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED| FR_MESSAGE_PART       | 61238 |  5501K|       |  8822   (1)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     2 |
|*  7 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN DESCENDING             | IX_FR_MESSAGE_PART_TS |  7908 |       |       |   631   (1)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     2 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   3 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   5 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   6 - filter("ID">=376894993815568384)
   7 - access("TS"<TO_TIMESTAMP(:2))
       filter(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("TS")+0>=:1 AND "TS"<TO_TIMESTAMP(:2))
```

We had to implement the mentioned Oracle-specific `+ 0` workaround and partition elimination bounds hardcoding in our custom ORM framework. It allows to retain the same fast paging performance after switching to partitioned tables with local indices.

But I wish much patience and sanity to those who venture to do the same switch without complete control of sql-building code.

It appears Oracle has too much pitfalls when partitioning and [paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241622/paging-with-oracle) are mixed together. For example, we found that Oracle 12's new `OFFSET ROWS / FETCH NEXT ROWS ONLY` [syntax sugar](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1) is almost unusable with local indexed partitioned tables as most of [analytic windowing functions](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/window-functions) it's based upon.

The shortest working query to fetch some page behind the first one is

```
select * from (select * from (
    select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(200) INDEX_RS_DESC(FR_MESSAGE_PART (TS)) */* from FR_MESSAGE_PART
where TS + 0 >= :1 and TS < :2
  and ID >= 376894993815568384 and ID < 411234940974268416
order by TS DESC) where ROWNUM <= 200) offset 180 rows;
```

Here is an example of [actual execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376329/jdbc-oracle-fetch-explain-plan-for-query/49927499#49927499) after running such query:

```
SQL_ID  c67mmq4wg49sx, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select * from (select * from (select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(200)
INDEX_RS_DESC("FR_MESSAGE_PART" ("TS")) GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS */ "ID",
"MESSAGE_TYPE_ID", "TS", "REMOTE_ADDRESS", "TRX_ID",
"PROTOCOL_MESSAGE_ID", "MESSAGE_DATA_ID", "TEXT_OFFSET", "TEXT_SIZE",
"BODY_OFFSET", "BODY_SIZE", "INCOMING" from "FR_MESSAGE_PART" where
"TS" + 0 >= :1 and "TS" < :2 and "ID" >= 376894993815568384 and "ID" <
411234940974268416 order by "TS" DESC) where ROWNUM <= 200) offset 180
rows

Plan hash value: 2499404919

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                 | Name                  | Starts | E-Rows |E-Bytes|E-Temp | Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   | Pstart| Pstop | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                          |                       |      1 |        |       |       |   640K(100)|          |       |       |     20 |00:00:00.01 |     322 |       |       |          |
|*  1 |  VIEW                                     |                       |      1 |    200 |   130K|       |   640K  (1)| 00:00:26 |       |       |     20 |00:00:00.01 |     322 |       |       |          |
|   2 |   WINDOW NOSORT                           |                       |      1 |    200 |   127K|       |   640K  (1)| 00:00:26 |       |       |    200 |00:00:00.01 |     322 |   142K|   142K|          |
|   3 |    VIEW                                   |                       |      1 |    200 |   127K|       |   640K  (1)| 00:00:26 |       |       |    200 |00:00:00.01 |     322 |       |       |          |
|*  4 |     COUNT STOPKEY                         |                       |      1 |        |       |       |            |          |       |       |    200 |00:00:00.01 |     322 |       |       |          |
|   5 |      VIEW                                 |                       |      1 |    780K|   487M|       |   640K  (1)| 00:00:26 |       |       |    200 |00:00:00.01 |     322 |       |       |          |
|*  6 |       SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY               |                       |      1 |    780K|    68M|    89M|   640K  (1)| 00:00:26 |       |       |    200 |00:00:00.01 |     322 | 29696 | 29696 |26624  (0)|
|   7 |        PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR           |                       |      1 |    780K|    68M|       |   624K  (1)| 00:00:25 |     3 |     2 |    400 |00:00:00.01 |     322 |       |       |          |
|*  8 |         COUNT STOPKEY                     |                       |      2 |        |       |       |            |          |       |       |    400 |00:00:00.01 |     322 |       |       |          |
|*  9 |          TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| FR_MESSAGE_PART       |      2 |    780K|    68M|       |   624K  (1)| 00:00:25 |     3 |     2 |    400 |00:00:00.01 |     322 |       |       |          |
|* 10 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN DESCENDING     | IX_FR_MESSAGE_PART_TS |      2 |    559K|       |       | 44368   (1)| 00:00:02 |     3 |     2 |    400 |00:00:00.01 |       8 |       |       |          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Outline Data
-------------

  /*+
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('12.1.0.2')
      DB_VERSION('12.1.0.2')
      OPT_PARAM('optimizer_dynamic_sampling' 0)
      OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_dsdir_usage_control' 0)
      FIRST_ROWS(200)
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$3")
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$2")
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$1")
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$4")
      NO_ACCESS(@"SEL$4" "from$_subquery$_004"@"SEL$4")
      NO_ACCESS(@"SEL$1" "from$_subquery$_001"@"SEL$1")
      NO_ACCESS(@"SEL$2" "from$_subquery$_002"@"SEL$2")
      INDEX_RS_DESC(@"SEL$3" "FR_MESSAGE_PART"@"SEL$3" ("FR_MESSAGE_PART"."TS"))
      END_OUTLINE_DATA
  */

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_004"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber">180)
   4 - filter(ROWNUM<=200)
   6 - filter(ROWNUM<=200)
   8 - filter(ROWNUM<=200)
   9 - filter("ID">=376894993815568384)
  10 - access("TS"<:2)
       filter((INTERNAL_FUNCTION("TS")+0>=:1 AND "TS"<:2))
```

Note how much actual fetched rows and time are better than optimizer estimations.

---

***Update***

Beware than even this optimal plan could fail down to slow local index full scan in case lower partition elimination bound was guessed too low that the lowest partition doesn't contain enough records to match query filters.

rleishman's [Tuning "BETWEEN" Queries](http://www.orafaq.com/node/1798) states:

> The problem is that an index can only scan on one column with a range
>   predicate (<, >, LIKE, BETWEEN). So even if an index contained both
>   the lower_bound and upper_bound columns, the index scan will return
>   all of the rows matching lower_bound <= :b, and then filter the rows
>   that do not match upper_bound >= :b.
>
> In the case where the sought value is somewhere in the middle, the
>   range scan will return half of the rows in the table in order to find
>   a single row. In the worst case where the most commonly sought rows
>   are at the top (highest values), the index scan will process almost
>   every row in the table for every lookup.

It means that, unfortunately, Oracle doesn't take into account the lower bound of a range scan filter until it reaches STOPKEY COUNT condition or scans the whole partition!

So we had to limit lower partition elimination bound heuristics to the same month the lower timestamp period bound falls into.
This defends against full index scans at expense of a risk of not showing some delayed transaction messages in the list.
But this can be easily resolved by extending the supplied time period if needed.

---

I've also tried to apply the same `+ 0` trick to force optimal plan with dynamic partition elimination bounds binding:

```
select * from (select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(40) INDEX_RS_DESC(FR_MESSAGE_PART (TS)) */ * from FR_MESSAGE_PART
where TS+0 >= :1 and TS < :2
  and ID >= :3 and ID+0 < :4
order by TS DESC) where ROWNUM <= 40;
```

The plan then still retains proper `STOPKEY COUNT` per partition but the partition elimination is lost for upper bound as may be noticed by `Pstart` column of plan table:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                      | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                               |                       |    40 | 26200 |  9083   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                                 |                       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   VIEW                                         |                       |   153 |    97K|  9083   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY                       |                       |   153 | 14076 |  9083   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   4 |     PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR                   |                       |   153 | 14076 |  9082   (1)| 00:00:01 |    10 |   KEY |
|*  5 |      COUNT STOPKEY                             |                       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED| FR_MESSAGE_PART       |   153 | 14076 |  9082   (1)| 00:00:01 |    10 |   KEY |
|*  7 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN DESCENDING             | IX_FR_MESSAGE_PART_TS | 11023 |       |   891   (1)| 00:00:01 |    10 |   KEY |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   3 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   5 - filter(ROWNUM<=40)
   6 - filter("ID">=TO_NUMBER(:3) AND "ID"+0<TO_NUMBER(:4))
   7 - access("TS"<TO_TIMESTAMP(:2))
       filter(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("TS")+0>=:1 AND "TS"<TO_TIMESTAMP(:2))
```

Comment: During investigation I was even considering using [zone maps](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/zone_maps.htm#DWHSG-GUID-BEA5ACA1-6718-4948-AB38-1F2C0335FDE4) to aid [partition pruning](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-65DA5654-970B-4056-BFBF-C300C9A8AA2A.htm#VLDBG14101) but this feature turned out to be [avaliable on Exadata only](http://afatkulin.blogspot.com.by/2014/08/zone-maps.html?showComment=1408454039191#c7734593287744777191).

Comment: In case nothing else helps, there are 4 ways to override plan for any sql externally (SQL Plan Baseline, SQL patch, SQL Profiles, Stored Outlines): https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fors.ru%2Fupload%2Fmagazine%2F05%2Fhttp_texts%2Frussia_ruoug_deev_sql_plans.html

Answer (score 1):

Is Dynamic SQL an option? That way you could "inject" the TRX_ID and CREATE_TS filter values eliminating the use of bind variables. Maybe then the generated plan would include COUNT STOPKEY.

By Dynamic SQL I meant for you to construct the SQL dynamically and then invoking it with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE or OPEN. By using this you are able to use your filters directly without bind variables. Example:

```
    v_sql VARCHAR2(1000) :=
    'select rd from (
        select /*+ INDEX(OUT_SMS OUT_SMS_CREATE_TS_TRX_ID_IX) */ rowid rd
        from OUT_SMS     
        where  TRX_ID between ' || v_trx_id_min || ' and ' || v_trx_id_maxb || '      
           and CREATE_TS between ' || v_create_ts_min|| ' and ' || v_create_ts_max || '
        order by CREATE_TS DESC, TRX_ID DESC
    ) where rownum <= 20';
```

then invoke it using:

```
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
```

or even:

```
    OPEN cursor_out FOR v_sql;
```

Comment: Emulate bind variables isn't interesting for performance. Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Please see the edited answer. The idea is not to use bind variables. How are you analyzing the table?