# Can JDBC statement run execution plan / explain plan?

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-execution-plan, explain, executequery

Can JDBC statement run explain plan on query string?

The code throws SQL exception
Error message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'plan'.
Stacktrace is null

I just copy from internet of using stmt.execute. However, it seems that stmt.execute() only Returns true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if it is an update count or there are no results

```java
conn = getEntityManager().unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
stmt = conn.createStatement();         
stmt.execute("explain plan for SELECT   1 from Dual"); // throws sql exception
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select plan_table_output from table(dbms_xplan.display())");
while (rs.next()) 
{
  System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: I don't think it will work, but you might be able to write a stored procedure which gets a text output from `EXPLAIN` on the database, and then call that proc from your Java code.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the thrown exception.

Comment: Yes that should work - how else would JDBC based SQL clients be able to do that? What exactly is the exception you get?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What makes you think JDBC-based SQL clients *can* do that?

Comment: @user207421 Because Oracle's own GUI client ("SQL Developer") is based on Java using JDBC. And I am using another JDBC based client that can do that. And because I have also done it myself through plain JDBC

Comment: I just copy from internet of using stmt.execute.
However, it seems that stmt.execute() only Returns
true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if it is an update count or there are no results

Comment: @ITpeople You need to read the API documentation of `Statement`. When the return value is `true`, you need to call `getResultSet()`, otherwise `getUpdateCount()`, process that result, then call `getMoreResults()` (where the returned boolean has the same meaning), do this until you get false **and** `getUpdateCount()` returns `-1`. See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14829425/466862).

Comment: error message:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'plan'.\n

stacktrace is null

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: `execute("explain plan for SELECT   1 from Dual");` does not return anything in Oracle. The code in the question should work, there is no need to check the return code of the `execute()` call (It seems the code was copied directly from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4376639/330315)).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You're right, I was thinking of database systems where the plan is returned as a result set.

Comment: what if the DB is sybase?